# Making a copy of a view in Laravel

Tags: laravel

Im new to Laravel and I'm trying no make a copy of a file named appApunts.blade.php form views into the public folder.
I tried to use Storage::copy but didn't make it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this,

```
\File::copy(base_path('views/appApunts.blade.php'),base_path('public/appApunts.blade.php'));
```